# Quantum Mechanics in practice

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, observables, quantum-states, quantum-measurements

Learning QM for the first time makes me feel like learning set of rules that can describe the quantum phenomena and applying them to predict what would happen to a given quantum state. This makes me wonder how theoretical physicist would set up the quantum state with a situation that they have in mind and how to make operators that they want to act on quantum state.

Likewise, how would experimental physicists set up the quantum state from the data that they get from experiments? My concern to this would be if an experiment couldn't detect some possible observables of that quantum state, what would happen if one decides to work with a quantum state that doesn't completely contain all the information?

I would like to have some intuition on how to use quantum mechanics to a phenomena that one would like to research on.

Comment: It is not the quantum states that one measures in quantum mechanics - but the *observables*, which are pretty much the same that in classical physics.

Comment: I tend to sleep better not over thinking whether the probabilities are truly random or not, or if we create a multiverse every time we make a choice, or whatnot. Leave it for now to specialists in the philosophy of science when first learning about QM :)

Comment: @James I don't think I'm asking anything about probabilities... I wanted to know how QM gets used in actual research.